# Weird output when using const char*, to_string() and c_str()

Tags: c++

I have a program that uses `to_string` to convert an `int` to a `string`, then converts that to a C string using `string::c_str()`, which is stored in an array of `const char*`. When the program outputs each `const char*`, the results are not what I unexpected. For the sample program below, which outputs a counter and an unchanging variable, I expected the output to consist of the counter, followed by an unchanging amount, then asterisks to separate:

> ```
> 1
> 10
> ***************
> 2
> 10
> ****************
> 3
> 10
> *****************
> …
> ```

Instead of the count up, each loop iteration always outputs the same value (which happens to be the value of the unchanging variable):

> ```
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> 10
> 10
> **************
> ```

The sample program used to produce the above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int order = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i, ++order) {
        const char* a[2];
        int b = 10;
        a[0] = to_string(order).c_str(); // these
        a[1] = to_string(b).c_str();     // are the
        cout << a[0] << endl;            // relevant
        cout << a[1] << endl;            // lines
        cout << "**************" << endl;
    }
}
```

Where is the mistake? Is it because the array elements have `const char *` type?

Comment: Where do you think the `std::string`'s that are backing those dangling pointers you're storing are retained? (hint: the adjective I used for the pointers should tell you something: they're *not* retained).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this line

```
a[0] = to_string(order).c_str();
```

`to_string(order)` generates a temporary string.  The result of `c_str()` is only valid as long as the temporary string exists, but the temporary string is destroyed after the statement.  `a[0]` is then left holding an invalid pointer.

To work around this, you'll need to store the strings somewhere so they don't go away immediately:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        int order=1;
        for(int i=1; i<10;++i,++order){
                const char* a[2];
                int b = 10;
                auto order_str = to_string(order);
                auto b_str = to_string(b);
                a[0] = order_str.c_str();
                a[1] = b_str.c_str();
                cout << a[0] << endl;
                cout << a[1] << endl;
                cout << "**************" << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you. how can i get the results i wanted? is there anyway to provide c_str() a non-tmp string?

Comment: @daydayup: There's various possibilities.  Can you make `a` be an array of `std::string`s instead of `const char *`s?

Comment: will it work if i first save the temp string to a variable and then use c_str?

Comment: no. actually a has to be const char* to serve as a parameter of a function

Comment: @daydayup: In that case, you'll need to store the `std::string`s in a variable so that they stay around.  I'll give an example.

Comment: @daydayup if this answer helped you to fix the problem, please accept the answer :)